# How to backup core data and images to ICloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

We're developing a chat application which consist of a core data database and lots of pictures in Documents folder.
What we would like to accomplish is to backup these files to ICloud on weekly schedule(like whatsapp is doing) and restore those files when the user reinstall the app.
I've looked for cloudkit sdk but couldnt find a proper solution for this usecase

Do you know is something like that possible and if it is which sdk or library should we use?

Thanks